# How to figure out which package a command is from at any particular time?

Tags: macros, packages, environments, debugging

I know there are some posts on this but I don't understand. So for instance I want to know which package contains `\restatable`.

I've tried `\show\restatable` but I don't understand what the relevant part of the log file

```
> \restatable=\long macro:
->\thmt@thisistheonetrue \thmt@restatable .
l.482 \show\restatable
```

means

I've found some posts about  latexdef but I don't know how that will work in a document.

Loaded packages:

```
\usepackage{adpwrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{mathbbol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\newcommand{\mypara}[1]{\noindent{\bfseries #1.}}

\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{agcolor}{blue!70!white}
\colorlet{jkcolor}{green!60!black}
\usepackage[textwidth=20mm]{todonotes}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
%\usepackage[bookmarks=true,colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=red]{hyperref}    
    \renewcommand{\definitionautorefname}{Definition}
    \newcommand{\remarkautorefname}{Remark}
%}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
```

The rest are in the siamart190516.cls

Comment: Please tell us which packages you load. (Who knows, `\restatable` may be defined in more than one package...)

Comment: @Mico added packages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `\show` you got

```latex
->\thmt@thisistheonetrue \thmt@restatable .
```

which looks like the package prefix in use is `thmt`. Then looking at your preamble we see `thmtools` - that looks likely for the prefix. Reading `thmtools.sty` we see `thmt@` in use but no `\restatable`. However, looking at all of the files that come with `thmtools`, in `thm-restate.sty` there is:

```latex
\newenvironment{restatable}{%
  \thmt@thisistheonetrue\thmt@restatable
}{%
  \endthmt@restatable
}
```

This will define `\restatable` and `\endrestatable`, so we have found the (likely) source.

Comment: Do you mean  thmtools?  I don't see a thmt package.

Comment: Like I said, we see the prefix `thmt` and we think 'ah, that might be `thmtools`: package prefixes in code are often shorter than the full package name

Answer (score 2):

One way to get a clue which package defines or redefines a command is to plant `\show`-commands in various places and look what changes. E.g. this

```
\documentclass{article}
\show\restatable
\usepackage{tabularx}
\show\restatable
\usepackage{thmtools}
\show\restatable

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

gives (shortened)

```
> \restatable=undefined.
l.24 \show\restatable

?
(.../tabularx.sty)
> \restatable=undefined.
l.26 \show\restatable

?
(.../thmtools.sty  more files ) 
> \restatable=\long macro:
->\thmt@thisistheonetrue \thmt@restatable .
l.28 \show\restatable
```

and so a good clue that thmtools is involved.